# How to open zip file without additional Nuget packages?

Tags: c#, zip

I have the following code:

```
    public static class PracticeFunction 
    {
        [FunctionName("LearningAboutFunctions")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile("https://examplesite.co.uk/file.zip", "myfile.zip");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way of opening the Zip file and extracting the contents without needing to install any additional nuget packages?

Comment: You can use ZipFile: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netcore-3.1 You don't have to download any nuget packages but you have to add an assembly reference

Comment: Search for "C# unzip file" in your favorite engine - the documentation for the builtin `ZipFile` class should be at or near the top.

Comment: try powershell command

Comment: @PaulSütterlin and D Stanley, you are assuming user is targeting >= 4.5 framework... if not, that functionality wouldn't be applicable. Please update your post to include what version you are targeting.

Comment: @Jordan1993 In the provided example, there's no attempt at unzipping a file. Currently the question is seeking opinions and or recommendations of which is off topic here unfortunately. It may help us help you if you could provide actual code that is causing an issue, otherwise, what are you seeking as an outcome here?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
using System.IO.Compression;

string startPath = @"C:\Users\host\Desktop\Folder";
            string zipPath = startPath + @"\Zipfile.zip";
            string extractPath = @"C:\Users\host\Desktop\Final Folder\";
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: A little suggestion: look at [Path.Combine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1) to combine your `startPath` and `zipPath`.